# How do I dynamically get the values?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

Where do I get the values?

Below is the script to track usertype, Here I have used custom variable to track the usertype..

```
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "Usertype", <<dynamically fill Usertype>>, 1)
```

In above script, how do I dynamically get the values

Example:
If it is the guest user, I need to fill dynamic value as "guest"

```
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "Usertype", guest, 1)
```

If user is member after logged in, I need to fill dynamic value as "member"

```
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "Usertype", member, 1)
```

Please anyone help me or give me a solution

Answer (score 1):

place hidden fields in the aspx part:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="User" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>
```

from code behind

```
User.Value = "XXXXXX";
```

And In the script

```
var varuser = document.getElementById("User").value;
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "Usertype", varuser, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also cal an method or property in your designer view:

```
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "Usertype", <%= Helper.GetUserType() %>, 1)
```